# How to enable System.out.println() while running Junit test in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

My java code is below:

```
package ex2_binarySearch;

public class Solution {
//  public int [] twoSum(int target, int [] numbers) {
    public int [] twoSum(int [] numbers, int target) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            int res = binarySearch(i, numbers.length, target - numbers[i], numbers);
            if(res != -1) {
                System.out.println("Yeah");
                return new int [] {i+1, res+1};
            }
        }
                System.out.println("Yeah Yeah");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not found");
    }

    public int binarySearch(int start, int end, int target, int [] numbers) {
        int L = start;
        int R = end;
        while (L < R) {
            int M = (L+R)/2;
            if(numbers[M] < target) {
                L = M+1;
            }
            else if(numbers[M] > target) {
                R = M-1;
            }
            else {
                return M;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Here is the Junit test:

```
package ex2_binarySearch;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import ex1.Solution;

public class SolutionTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
    /*
        Solution s = new Solution();
        int [] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int target = 4;
        int [] res = s.twoSum(numbers, target);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {1, 3}, res);
        */
        Solution s = new Solution();
        int [] numbers = {-3,3,4,90};
        int target = 0;
        int [] res = s.twoSum(numbers, target);
        assertArrayEquals(new int[] {1, 2}, res);
    }

}
```

When I execute the Junit test, nothing prints out in the eclipse console. Why is that and how can I enable it? I notice that if I write a program with main function and just run the main instead of junit, then the print will get to the console.

Comment: I suggest you to use some logging library instead, as log4j for example

Answer (score -1):

This prints yeah yeah , which is a log statement you have on your main class. You have set these up on your Test file and run the tests

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setOut(System.out);
    System.setErr(System.err);
}

@After
public void closeStream() throws Exception {
    System.setOut(null);
    System.setErr(null);
}
```

Comment: I paste your code in the Solution class. Nothing prints out. Then I cut-paste in Junit test. Nothing prints out. How do I use it?

Comment: When I used the same set up on my junit class , I did get informative messages like yeah yeah , yeah etc. The tone of your comment can be a bit more polite

Comment: hi, not intended to be rude. Can you paste your junit code here? I double check my code, it still does not work. I do get two errors. It says Before and After cannot be resolved to a type.